# SimpleCV: Removing lines I previously drew?

Tags: python-2.7, simplecv

I'm trying to do edge detection with SimpleCV on a RasPi by first finding all the lines in an image and then filtering items set based on location, intersect angle and color. I have the filtering figured out, but am having difficulty displaying the image with the filtered lines drawn in.

Currently I am can draw the full line set with

> ```
> handle_lin = my_lines_full.draw()
> handle_img = some_image.show()
> ```

and the filtered line set independently with

> ```
> handle_lin = my_lines_filtered.draw()
> handle_img = some_image.show()
> ```

but since this method also displays the full line set, no difference is seen when I do them in the same script. Whats the best way to erase the layer that stores the line drawings or selectively remove elements of the drawing?

Answer (score 0):

Sovled(-ish):

Seems as though the `some_lines.draw()` command toggles line sets so by repeating the .draw() command before updating the lines set I can clear the layer that is displayed on the image.